# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'http' - Windows 10

Tags: php, laravel, http

I am running PHP `8.0.3` on my windows 10 machine and trying to enable HTTP extension. I have downloaded the HTTP package from [PECL HTTP](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pecl_http/). When I try to start PHP I get the below error.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'http' (tried: C:\Php8.0.3\ext\http (The specified module could not be found), C:\Php8.0.3\ext\php_http.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'http' (tried: C:\Php8.0.3\ext\http (The specified module could not be found), C:\Php8.0.3\ext\php_http.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I did figure it out. Windows error was very unhelpful and only found this out after digging through some documentation.

The `http` extensions relies on the `raphf` extension, which I didn't have installed. On Linux, it would alert me to that, but on windows it just throws a generic "couldn't find extension". Probably the same thing for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

One of a few things is happening:

1. The file doesn't exist in the filepath it's being looked for in. Check the location in the error message or
2. The file exists, but it's permissions are wrong.

Hint, it's the former ;)

Comment: You are incorrect. I'm getting the same error, all perms are granted on it, and it's definitely in the location as a simple `ls` reveals.

Comment: See my answer above